# How add mask to input with knockout javascript?

Tags: magento2, knockoutjs, zipcode, input

I need to add a mask to postcode input (ex: 99.999-99), so I have `Vendor/Theme/Magento_Checkout/web/template/form/element/zipcode.html` with:

```
<input class="input-text col s12 zipcode" type="text" data-bind="
    value: value,
    valueUpdate: 'keyup',
    hasFocus: focused,
    attr: {
        name: inputName,
        placeholder: placeholder,
        'aria-describedby': getDescriptionId(),
        'aria-required': required,
        'aria-invalid': error() ? true : 'false',
        id: uid,
        disabled: disabled
    }" name="postcode" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="false" id="zipcode">
```

And my `checkout_index_index.xml` :

```
<item name="postcode" xsi:type="array">
<!-- post-code field has custom UI component -->
<item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/form/element/post-code</item>
<item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
    <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="string">true</item>
</item>
<item name="config" xsi:type="array">
    <!-- Assigning a new template -->
    <item name="elementTmpl" xsi:type="string">Magento_Checkout/form/element/zipcode</item>
</item>
```

I Already have `Vendor/Module/etc/zip_codes.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Directory:etc/zip_codes.xsd">

    <!-- Specify the country ISO code-->
    <zip countryCode="BR">
        <codes>
            <code id="pattern_1" active="true" example="12345">^[0-9]{5}$</code>
            <code id="pattern_2" active="true" example="12345-678">^[0-9]{2}\.[0-9]{3}\-[0-9]{3}$</code>
        </codes>
    </zip>
</config>
```